# Perl: Opening File

Tags: perl

I am trying to open the file received as argument.

When i store the argument in to the global variable **open** works successfully.

But

If I use give make it as my open fails to **open** the file.

What is the reason.

```
#use strict;
use warnings;

#my $FILE=$ARGV[0];   #open Fails to open the file $FILE

$FILE=$ARGV[0];        #Works Fine with Global $FILE
open(FILE)
    or
die "\n ". "Cannot Open the file specified :ERROR: $!". "\n";
```

Comment: This style of perl is **way** obsolete.  You would be much better off doing open my $file, "<", $ARGV[ 0 ]...or better yet don't call open at all and just read from ARGV.  (Perl assumes the arguments are files to be opened for input, and opens them automagically for you.)

Comment: Unary open is documented to work only on package variables.

Comment: @William: Oughtn’t there be an encoding there?  `open(FH, "< :encoding(UTF-8)", $pathname)`

Comment: @tchrist Good catch, and it makes a strong argument in favor of just reading from ARGV.

Comment: @William: Setting the encoding on ARGV is a bit tricky: it generally requires the `PERL_UNICODE` envariable or the corresponding `perl ‑CSD` command-line flag, but those only work if we’re talking UTF‑8.  The `use open` pragma, however, can handle alternate encodings. To pass that in with an envariable requires a bit of sneakiness: `PERL5OPT='-Mopen=:std,IN,:encoding(MacRoman),OUT,:utf8'` works.

Comment: The fact that you have to comment out `use strict;` is your first clue that you are doing something wrong. Pay attention to the error messages that Perl is giving you.

Comment: @Ether: presumably that's what prompted this question

Comment: @ysth: if so, he should have provided the error message he got and asked what it meant.

Comment: @Ether: I figure s/he did correctly interpret the error message, tried to switch to lexicals, and ended up with this question (a very different question than what does a strict-induced error indicate)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unary open works only on package (global) variables. This is documented on [the manpage](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).

A better way to open a file for reading would be:

```
my $filename = $ARGV[0];           # store the 1st argument into the variable
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die $!; # open the file using lexically scoped filehandle

print <$fh>; # print file contents
```

P.S. always use `strict` and `warnings` while debugging your Perl scripts.

Comment: This answer misses the point.  The simple question was why unary open works only with package variables.  The simple answer is that it is because it is thus documented. All else is frosting on a missing cake.

Comment: @tchrist: ok, I added this to the answer

Comment: Thanks. I don’t usually downvote answers that have made a good try at it (which is why I didn’t do so here). I prefer pointing out what they missed.  Thanks for fixing it.

Answer (score 7):

It's all in [`perldoc -f open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html):

> If EXPR is omitted, the scalar variable of the same name as
>   the FILEHANDLE contains the filename.  (Note that lexical
>   variables--those declared with "my"--will not work for this
>   purpose; so if you're using "my", specify EXPR in your call
>   to open.)

Note that this isn't a very good way to specify the file name.  As you can see, it has a hard constraint on the variable type it's in, and either the global variable it requires or the global filehandle it opens are usually best avoided.

Using a lexical filehandle keeps its scope in control, and handles closing automatically:

```
open my $fh, '<', "filename" or die "string involving $!";
```

And if you're taking that file name from the command line, you could possibly do away with that `open` or any handle altogether, and use the plain `<>` operator to read from command-line arguments or STDIN.  (see comments for more on this)

Comment: Good point: It’s usually a lot better to use magic ARGV than an explicit open. But add `if (!@ARGV && -t STDIN) { warn "$0: reading from stdin...\n" }` to help people whose systems lack a proper `^T` tty char. However, magic ARGV only uses stdin when `@ARGV` is initially empty, not when it is exhausted; your answer suggests otherwise.

Comment: @tchrist: yes and no... after `<>` exhausted ARGV and returned undef once (what you were saying), it'll start again, with an empty @ARGV if you haven't done anything about it, hence fall back to STDIN (what I was saying).  I'd concede most people won't get past the first undef spontaneously and edit.

Comment: I have no doubt you do. :) I was just defending what I initially wrote wasn't *that* off.

Answer (score 6):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file_name = shift @ARGV;
open(my $file, '<', $file_name) or die $!;
…
close($file);
```

Always use `strict` and `warnings`. If either of them complains, fix the code, do not comment out the pragmas. You can also `use autodie` to avoid the explicit `or die` after open, see [autodie](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autodie).

Comment: +1 and it needs to be said again:  If `strict` complains, it means that you need to fix your code, not that you need to comment out `strict`.

Comment: I’ve said it before, I’ll say it again: *This answer misses the point. The simple question was why unary open works only with package variables. The simple answer is that it is because it is thus documented. All else is frosting on a missing cake.* Also, you forgot to specify the encoding as in `open(FH, "< :encoding(UTF-8)", $path)`. And if one is being so very careful, shouldn’t one also test `@ARGV` for reasonility?  Finally, how can you know they do **NOT** want to allow filenames like `-` in the standard Unix fashion of specifying std{in,out,whatever}?

Comment: Also, this is a really bad idiom.  Perl already handles automatically opening files listed as arguments via ARGV.  In perl, there is almost never a good reason to explicitly open a file whose name is given in @ARGV

Comment: It’s not meant as an idiom. And chances are that showing a user how to open a file could be more helpful than telling him that “unary open is documented to work only on package variables.” Or maybe not, but that’s what we have multiple answers for after all.

Comment: @zoul I agree that it is good to give examples, and my comment was not meant to be a criticism of your response so much as a warning to the unwary reader.  Much perl code seems to be written by people who do not know that perl does a lot of this work for free.

Comment: Ah, yes, now I understand. Sorry for the egocentrism. Yes, it would be a bit clumsy to write the code this way if one would just want to process files from ARGV.

Answer (score 3):

From [Perl's docs for open()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)

> If EXPR is omitted, the scalar variable of the same name as the FILEHANDLE contains the filename. (Note that lexical variables--those declared with my--will not work for this purpose; so if you're using my, specify EXPR in your call to open.)